# Problem with cases environment when used in a stack

Tags: math-mode, stackengine

I use the following code when I want to typeset math which was kindly written by Stephen B. Segletes but I have a  problem when I try to use in it the `cases` environment. There is no problem with the `cases` code as when I use it outside the `\SS` it works. Why is that happenning? How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\everymath{\displaystyle}



\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\stackalignment{l}
\setstackgap{S}{10pt}
\def\SS#1{\noindent\addstackgap[3pt]{\Shortstack{#1}}\vspace{2ex}\par\vfil}


\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\SS{
\vec{H}_{1}=\vec{H}_{3}=0\Rightarrow \vec{B}_{1}=\vec{B}_{3}=0\\
\vec{H}_{2}=K_{0}\hat{x}\\
\vec{B}_{2}=\begin{cases}
\mu_{1}(z)\vec{H}=\mu_{1}(z)K_{0}\hat{x} & 0<z<h_{1}\\
\mu_{2}H=\mu_{2}K_{0}\hat{x} & h_{1}<z<h
\end{cases}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the `stackengine` approach to formatting multiple lines of math is quite different from that of `amsmath`, where `cases` is defined.  although i haven't tried to combine them, the philosophy is so different that i haven't much confidence that they would be compatible.

Comment: could you link to the question/answer where you got the code?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton what do you mean? By multiple lines of code you mean the `cases` environment or the whole approach with the `stackengine`?Don't you think that it is a good way to write multiple lines of code?

Comment: @Adam -- `stackengine` addresses only the presentation (visual) aspect of the material; `amsmath` tries to take into consideration the "meaning" (as it might be interpreted by someone who is visually impaired and requires an audio presentation).  it's roughly equivalent to "presentation mathml" vs. "content mathml".  i'd rather not try to address whether one is "better" than the other, but since the structure of the two is significantly different, how to make them work together seamlessly isn't obvious, and probably not trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add braces around `cases`. However, I can't understand what's the purpose of using another package. Here's an example, where I removed all the unnecessary things (and also the final `\vfil`). I renamed your personal command, because it's a *very* bad idea to redefine `\SS`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\stackalignment{l}
\setstackgap{S}{10pt}
\newcommand\AdamSS[1]{\noindent\addstackgap[3pt]{\Shortstack{#1}}\vspace{2ex}\par}%\vfil}

\begin{document}

\AdamSS{
\vec{H}_{1}=\vec{H}_{3}=0\Rightarrow \vec{B}_{1}=\vec{B}_{3}=0\\
\vec{H}_{2}=K_{0}\hat{x}\\
\vec{B}_{2}={\begin{cases}
\mu_{1}(z)\vec{H}=\mu_{1}(z)K_{0}\hat{x} & 0<z<h_{1}\\
\mu_{2}H=\mu_{2}K_{0}\hat{x} & h_{1}<z<h
\end{cases}}
}

\noindent$\!\begin{aligned}
\vec{H}_{1}&=\vec{H}_{3}=0\Rightarrow \vec{B}_{1}=\vec{B}_{3}=0\\
\vec{H}_{2}&=K_{0}\hat{x}\\
\vec{B}_{2}&=
  \begin{cases}
  \mu_{1}(z)\vec{H}=\mu_{1}(z)K_{0}\hat{x} & 0<z<h_{1}\\
  \mu_{2}H=\mu_{2}K_{0}\hat{x} & h_{1}<z<h
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]